# setInterval ejecuta 50 veces la función pasada

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Tengo una función que quiero que se ejecute cada 15 segundos, según he leído la mejor manera es usando setInterval(). El problema está en que cada vez que le toca ejecutarse se ejecuta 50 veces el console.log().

```
const press = () => {
    console.log('press')
};

setInterval(() => {
    press();
}, 15000);
```

Este es un ejemplo sencillo de lo que quiero hacer, mi idea es usar esta función para hacer una petición a una API y actualizar los datos, pero es imposible si se lanza 50 veces por ejecución.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Dónde estas ejecutando este `setInterval()`? Todo apunta a que donde lo estás ejecutando lo ejecutas 50 veces, y ese es el problema real. Por cierto, solo te haría falta usar: `setInterval(press, 15000);` porque `press()` ya es una función y es lo que necesita como parámetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, todo apunta a que el problema no está en que se llame 50 veces por iteración a `press()`, si no que el código donde tienes tu `setInterval()` lo ejecutas 50 veces, por lo que creas 50 temporizadores que llaman a la misma función.

Para continuar, tu código podría reducirse a:

```js
const press = () => {
    console.log('press')
};

setInterval(press, 15000);
```

Porque `press` ya es una función, y [el primer parámetro de `setInterval()` puede ser una función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval), sin tener que crear una función para llamar a dicha función (que es lo que has hecho en tu código).

Por último, existen varios métodos para evitar repetir un temporizador múltiples veces.

La más sencilla es gestionar haberlo hecho mediante una variable de ámbito global:

```js
/* Variable de ámbito global para gestionar el temporizador */
let temporizador = false;

const press = () => {
    console.log('press')
};

/* Comprobamos si ya hemos agregado previamente el temporizador */
if (temporizador === false) {
  /* Marcamos como agregado el temporizador */
  temporizador = setInterval(press, 15000);
}

/* Para cancelar el temporizador se puede usar:
clearInterval(temporizador);
temporizador = false;
*/
```